# Editing the textContent or innerHTML kills eventListener

Tags: javascript, forms, select, input

I'm starting with js so please forgive me obvious mistakes. I'm trying to recreate select input with few options to styleable markup.

Briefly what I'm trying to do:

1. Hide select
2. Create a parent div with text of first option and append it instead of original hidden select.
3. Add eventListener on click to toggle class (it shows and hides children elements)
4. Create inner divs with values and text of options from original hidden select.
5. Add eventListener for each of them to replace a value of select.

These few lines of js and few lines of css gives my easy to style select.

```js
// Define select and options
var select = document.getElementById('select');
var children = select.children;

// Recreate select via divs and keep same class
select.style.display = 'none';
var selectNew = document.createElement('div');
selectNew.className = select.classList;
selectNew.textContent = select.children[0].text;
select.parentNode.insertBefore(selectNew, select);
selectNew.addEventListener('click', function() {
  toggleChildren();
});

function toggleChildren() {
  selectNew.classList.toggle('active');
}

// remap children
var childArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  var child = document.createElement('div');
  child.innerHTML = select.children[i].text;
  child.dataset.value = select.children[i].value;
  selectNew.appendChild(child);
  childArray.push(child);

  child.addEventListener("click", function () {
    selectChoice();
  });
}

function selectChoice() {
  var which = childArray.indexOf( event.target || event.srcElement);
  select.value = children[which].value;
  // selectNew.textContent = children[which].text;
}
```

```css
.select {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 3em;
  background: #eee;
}
.select > div {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.select > div:nth-child(1) {
  top: 2em;
}
.select > div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 4em;
}
.select > div:nth-child(3) {
  top: 6em;
}
.select > div:nth-child(4) {
  top: 8em;
}
.select > div:nth-child(5) {
  top: 10em;
}
.select > div:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
.select.active > div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<select name="sortby" id="select" class="select">
  <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="val3">Value 3</option>
  <option value="val4">Value 4</option>
  <option value="val5">Value 5</option>
</select>
```

Whenever I try to update a text inside my parent element to show text of selected option via:

```
selectNew.textContent = children[which].text;
```

It kills previously added event Listener for this element. Can someone help me to understand what do I do wrong? That am I missing in behaviour of eventListeners?

Comment: Thank you so much! As I said I'm staring now and its difficult on the beginning but its a big fun. Is it any easy answeat why this one isnt working?

`select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  alert('select changed');
})`

Thank you so much again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't kill your event, you are removing your option elements by setting the textContent so there is nothing to display when you click on the div. You need to set the textContent of the first TextNode of your div.

```js
// Define select and options
var select = document.getElementById('select');
var children = select.children;

// Recreate select via divs and keep same class
select.style.display = 'none';
var selectNew = document.createElement('div');
selectNew.className = select.classList;
selectNew.textContent = select.children[0].text;
select.parentNode.insertBefore(selectNew, select);
selectNew.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  toggleChildren(e);
});

function toggleChildren() {
  selectNew.classList.toggle('active');
}

// remap children
var childArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  var child = document.createElement('div');
  child.innerHTML = select.children[i].text;
  child.dataset.value = select.children[i].value;
  selectNew.appendChild(child);
  childArray.push(child);

  child.addEventListener("click", function () {
    selectChoice();
  });
}

function selectChoice() {
  var which = childArray.indexOf( event.target || event.srcElement);
  select.value = children[which].value;

  //get the first textnode and set its textContent
  selectNew.childNodes[0].textContent = children[which].text;
}
```

```css
.select {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 3em;
  background: #eee;
}
.select > div {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.select > div:nth-child(1) {
  top: 2em;
}
.select > div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 4em;
}
.select > div:nth-child(3) {
  top: 6em;
}
.select > div:nth-child(4) {
  top: 8em;
}
.select > div:nth-child(5) {
  top: 10em;
}
.select > div:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
.select.active > div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<select name="sortby" id="select" class="select">
  <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="val3">Value 3</option>
  <option value="val4">Value 4</option>
  <option value="val5">Value 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! As I said I'm staring now and its difficult on the beginning but its a big fun. Is it any easy answeat why this one isnt working?

`select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  alert('select changed');
})`

Thank you so much again

Answer (score 2):

The line you refer to does cause the problem, but not because it kills listener. It actually replaces the entire content of your `selectNew` with text.
What you want is replace the text of the first child, which is the textContent node.

If you change the line to:

```
selectNew.firstChild.textContent = children[which].text;
```

then everything works as expected.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wintvelt/74k3g47v/).

**Bonus to answer**
As to the additional question to add a listener to change event:
You cannot only use a listener for 'change' event on a div, only on form elements like input.

However, you can detect the change inside your click handler, like so:

```
function selectChoice() {
    var which = childArray.indexOf(event.target || event.srcElement);
    select.value = children[which].value;
    if (selectNew.firstChild.textContent != children[which].text) {
        alert('select value has been changed');
        selectNew.firstChild.textContent = children[which].text;
    }
}
```

Updated [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wintvelt/3uLmn6vv/)

Comment: Thank you so much! As I said I'm staring now and its difficult on the beginning but its a big fun.  To avoid asking next question, can I use your js barin to help me with next small problem? Why this one isn't working for me? Thank you very much wintvelt! Cant thank enough!!!

`select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  alert('select changed');
})`

Thank you so much again

Comment: You're welcome! If you want to use my JSFiddle and update: You can change whatever you want on the link I provided (click Run to test). But you can't save. If you want that too: you can create your own (free) account, and then click on the 'Fork' button in my Fiddle. You can then update and save to do whatever you like.

Comment: I can belive how helpful you are! I owe you a beer whenever you close to middle UK! There you go, I just would like to detect whenever the value of select changed http://jsfiddle.net/pawelgrzybek/gym4wnLu/1/ Very (bootom of js tab)

Comment: Thank you so much again!